# typeorm return limited rows with relations

Tags: typeorm

I need to return relational data with limited rows, I have seen solutions using query builder how can we achieve the same thing using standard **typeorm** events?

```
return await Product.find({ relations: ['productSizes', 'productColors'] });
```

Comment: do you mean get limited rows from `productSizes` or `productColors` limited?

Comment: no, limit rows from main relation i.e Product

Comment: @Youba I'm struggling with the query to limit "children". In this example that would be productSizes or productColors, is it possible to do?

Comment: @igor_c I think you should use query builder instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make the limit for your product entity, you only need to add `take:numberTolimit`

```
return await Product.find({ relations: ['productSizes', 'productColors'],take:10 });
```

*Ps : you can use  `skip` - offset from where entities should be taken.*

Comment: Thats nice dont know why this wasnt mentioned in the documentation keep up the good work!

Comment: you can find it here [find-options](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md)